# Register Route in ASP .NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I was going to register a route such as below in ASP .NET MVC3:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "SearchRoute", // Route name
            "Report/Search/{code}/{quarter}/{year}/{receivedBegin}/{receivedEnd}/{transactionBegin}/{transactionEnd}/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new {
                controller = "Report",
                action = "Search",
                page = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

That route will link to this function in a controller named Report:

```
public ActionResult Search(string code, int? quarter, int? year, 
            DateTime? receivedBegin, DateTime? receivedEnd,
            DateTime? transactionBegin, DateTime? transactionEnd, int? page=1)
```

I expected that links generated by Html.ActionLink to that function will be generated like:
Report/Search/10/2/2012/04-30-2012/04-01-2012/04-30-2012

When I generate a link using Html.ActionLink, the link generated is as such:

```
Report/Search?code=100&quarter=2&year=2012&receivedBegin=04-01-2012&receivedEnd=04-30-2012&transactionBegin=04-01-2012&transactionEnd=04-30-2012
```

What should I do to generate a result as I expected? Thank you.

**Update**

This is the code I use to create the link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("First", "Search", new { 
    code = currentCode, 
    quarter = currentQuarter, 
    year = currentYear, 
    receivedBegin = currentReceivedBegin, 
    receivedEnd = currentReceivedEnd, 
    transactionBegin = currentTransactionBegin, 
    transactionEnd = currentTransactionEnd }, null).
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to generate the link. Also, is the rule you posted the first in your `RegisterRoutes` method?

Comment: Did you remove registration for default route. It seems Default route is used to generate the url. Else put this route before default route

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this is the code I use: @Html.ActionLink("First", "Search", new { code = currentCode, quarter = currentQuarter, year = currentYear, 
                                   receivedBegin = currentReceivedBegin, receivedEnd = currentReceivedEnd, 
                                   transactionBegin = currentTransactionBegin, transactionEnd = currentTransactionEnd }, null). No this is not the first route I registered. Do I have to register this first?

Comment: @Manas I registered the route first. Now the link generation works, but it says that an error occured because there is a ':' character in the url

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan for information, receivedBegin, receivedEnd, transactionBegin, and transactionEnd are all DateTime

Comment: Url should not contain ':' character, can you please post the generated url

Comment: @Manas Report/Search/200/2/2012/04/01/2012%2000%3a00%3a00/04/30/2012%2000%3a00%3a00/04/01/2012%2000%3a00%3a00/04/30/2012%2000%3a00%3a00/2 I suspect that there are ':' in the DateTimes

Comment: Yes '%3A' is ':' character, you can use different date format like currentReceivedBegin.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy")

Comment: @Manas when I try to put the url manually (I wrote Report/Search/200/2/2012/04-01-2012/04-30-2012/04-01-2012/04-30-2012/1 on the address bar) it works, but when I generate the link using Html.ActionLink, it doesn't.

Comment: ok, in Html.Action you can modify like from receivedBegin = currentReceivedBegin to receivedBegin = currentReceivedBegin.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No this is not the first route I registered. Do I have to register this first?

Yes. The rules in your `RegisterRoutes` method of `global.asax` should go from top to bottom in order of specificity, therefore this route should definitely be at (or at least near) the top.

The default route should always be the last one.